Mobile Application tab item edit
I have a custom screen with a tab, when clicking the 'Edit' button in the tab of the mobile app, a checkbox appears, I would like to customize the checkbox on fieldupdated so that if the checkbox is checked some of the columns of the tab item to change values, how can I implement this?
NB: the checkboxes are not a field on the screen, it is a checkbox that only appears on the mobile app.
Edit button:

The checkboxes:

